# How do you draw vertical line using coreplot CPPlotSymbol?

Tags: objective-c, charts, core-plot

How do I draw a vertical line on plotSymbol using Custom PlotSymbol?
If it would be grateful, give any samples regarding that.

Sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply create a CGPath that describes the outline of your custom symbol. Here's a sample from CPTestApp (in the CorePlot/examples folder):

```
CPPlotSymbol *symbol = [[[CPPlotSymbol alloc] init] autorelease];
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0., 0.);

CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0., 0., 10., 10.));
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(1.5, 4., 3., 3.));
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(5.5, 4., 3., 3.));
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 5., 2.);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, 5., 3.3, 2.8, 0., pi, TRUE);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

symbol.customSymbolPath = path;
symbol.usesEvenOddClipRule = YES;
CGPathRelease(path);
```

You can set the `plotSymbol` property on the scatter plot to apply your symbol to every point or use the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` or `-symbolsForScatterPlot:recordIndexRange:` datasource method to apply it to some of the points.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. is it support iphone os?

Comment: Yes, nearly everything in Core Plot is cross-platform between MacOS and iOS. In cases where there are platform differences (e.g., NSView vs. UIView) there is usually a platform-specific implementation of that feature.

Comment: I'm not able to get this working in my application in CorePlot 0.9 - any suggestions?

Comment: @Johnus Ask a new question with details about what you've tried so far.