# Core Plot drawing a straight y axis line with the labels on top

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

For the image below

[image]

Does anyone know how to get those horizontal lines with the numbers on top of them ? All I can get so fat is to color the ticks themselves and the numbers standing to the right of them. Any ideas how this can be achieved ?

Comment: Did u have a look to this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226423/how-do-you-draw-vertical-line-using-coreplot-cpplotsymbol

Comment: @tiguero nope but I am not really sure what that does (I tried it but it didnt have any visible effects)

Comment: yeh i might be wrong actually i misread it it is mentioned vertical lines while u want horizontal lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `majorGridLineStyle` properties on your axes. Also check the `minorGridLineStyle` property. You can see an example in the CPTestApp. For more details check [this google forum.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/coreplot-discuss/J2o6cQVzVW0)

for eg:-

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *yMajorGridLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle]; 
yMajorGridLineStyle.lineCap = kCGLineCapRound; 
yMajorGridLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor whiteColor]; 
yMajorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0; 

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet; 
CPTXYAxis *yAxis = axisSet.yAxis; 
yAxis.majorGridLineStyle = yMajorGridLineStyle;
```

In order to move the numbers to the right side of the axis, you can use,

```
yAxis.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;.
```

Also use,

```
yAxis.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentBottom;
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! I also needed to add "yAxis.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentBottom;" so that the labels are placed like in the picture.

Comment: @Cemre, Thanks for accepting. I have updated the answer with your suggestion for the benefit of others.